# Permission denied When trying to access NLTK_DATA directory: [Errno 13]: Permission denied: 'root/nltk_data'

Tags: linux, docker, nltk

I'm trying to access NLTK_DATA directory after installing ChatterBot and I can access the directory where the model are stored i order to be used by chatterbot.

Even after I set an env variable like explained on the [doc](https://www.nltk.org/data.html) I'm still facing the `permission denied` error.

I'm using this Dockerfile:

```
# Dockerfile

FROM python:3.8-buster

# install nginx
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install nginx vim -y --no-install-recommends
COPY ./vaana_app/nginx.default /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log

# copy source and install dependencies
RUN mkdir -p /opt/app
RUN mkdir -p /opt/app/pip_cache
RUN mkdir -p /opt/app/vaana_app
COPY ./vaana_app/requirements.txt /opt/app/
COPY ./vaana_app/start-server.sh /opt/app/
#COPY .pip_cache /opt/app/pip_cache/
COPY vaana_app /opt/app/vaana_app/
WORKDIR /opt/app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --cache-dir /opt/app/pip_cache
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /opt/app

RUN [ "python", "-c", "import nltk; nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger', download_dir='/usr/local/nltk_data')" ]

ENV NKTL_DATA=/usr/local/nltk_data

# start server
EXPOSE 8020
STOPSIGNAL SIGTERM
CMD ["/opt/app/start-server.sh"]
```

Error Image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OfyU.png)

Console error 1:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBRTZ.png)
Console error 2:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xt6mt.png)

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: please attach a link in the question to the docs you were using

Comment: Here is the link of the official doc: https://www.nltk.org/data.html

Comment: it looks like you don't have permission when installing nltk so it puts it in your home dir. just to confirm, can you please run `ls -la /usr/local/nltk_data/` and `id` in the Dockerfile after and before installing nltk?

Comment: The issues is the library still look at `/root/nltk` instead of the `/usr/local/nltk_data` like specified in ENV variable.

Comment: When I add `ls -la /usr/local/nltk_data/` and `id`
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Sep  9 11:59 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Sep  9 11:59 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Sep  9 11:59 taggers

uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)

As you can see I'm running it as root

Comment: please while downloading the package run these commands `import getpass;
getpass.getuser()`

Comment: I tried with this `RUN [ "python", "-c", "import nltk; nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger', download_dir='/usr/local/nltk_data')", "import getpass; getpass.getuser()" ]` but same error..

Comment: yes but what is the output from this? it should show the running username

Comment: It displays `root`

Comment: please try replacing your current python lines with `python -m nltk.downloader -d $NLTK_DATA averaged_perceptron_tagger` and set the environment variable before installing the package. if `averaged_perceptron_tagger` is problematic try using `all` instead

Comment: It seems like this nltk.downloader doesn't work with this version:
I tried: `RUN [ "python", "-m", "import nltk; nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger', -d $NLTK_DATA)" ]`

Comment: Installing all packages also doesn't fix the error..

Comment: after sending the GET request to /api/chatbot did you check the container logs? and can you include them **in the question** also

Comment: I added the console error on the question..

Comment: can you run `ls -la` like with `/usr/local/nltk_data` but this time with `/root/nltk_data` dir? `ls -la /root/nltk_data`

Comment: When I run the container in interactive and run `ls -la /root/nltk_data` there is no such file or directory.

Comment: Unless I install it without ENV variables I get this with the ls command:
`drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Sep  9 13:34 . - 
drwx------ 1 root root 4096 Sep  9 13:34 .. - 
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Sep  9 13:35 taggers`

Comment: I change the permission to `/root/nltk_data` with `chmod -R 777 /root/nltk_data` but same permission error..

Comment: can you try and add `--privileged` to your `docker run` command and try again?

Comment: I tried many times with `--privileged` but always same permission error..

Comment: Sorry @PapeAlioune, not a clue 

Comment: Yeah thanks man for all the help you provided..

Answer (score 0):

You may try to switch 2 lines

```
RUN [ "python", "-c", "import nltk; nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger', download_dir='/usr/local/nltk_data')" ]

ENV NKTL_DATA=/usr/local/nltk_data
```

with

```
ENV NLTK_DATA=/usr/local/nltk_data

RUN [ "python", "-c", "import nltk; nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger', download_dir='/usr/local/nltk_data')" ]
```

**EDIT**

There is a typo, please use NLTK_DATA instead of NKTL_DATA.

Regarding stack trace, nltk tries to create a directory without enough permission

(code generating the error from nltk/download.py):

```py
        # Ensure the download_dir exists
        if not os.path.exists(download_dir):
            os.mkdir(download_dir)
        if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(download_dir, info.subdir)):
            os.mkdir(os.path.join(download_dir, info.subdir))
```

Comment: Could you try to add this before ntk.download : nltk.data.path.append('/usr/local/nltk_data')

Comment: Same with the `append('/usr/local/nltk_data')` parameter..

Comment: Thanks @edijon for the typo but it's the same issue..

Comment: @PapeAlioune, this issue seems related : https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/issues/802   maybe it can help : https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/issues/802#issuecomment-311496499